# Changing the value of what a pointer is pointing to in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am getting a pointer to a string passed as an argument to the function, and I need to change a few characters in the string. I'm copying the string to a char array and editing what I need to just fine, but I need to change the original string that is being pointed to into the new char[] I just created.

The function has to return void, and because the pointer being passed is just a copy of the one from main, setting it to point to the new char[] won't do anything as it will just be deleted when the function ends, so I need to actually change the string being pointed to.

```
*str = &newstr[0]
```

This is giving me the compiler error: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast.

```
*str = newstr
```

And this is segfaulting when I run the program.

Here is the full function:

```
void replace(char* str, char toReplace, char replaceWith) {
  int strLen = strlen(src);
  char newstr[strLen];
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < strLen; i++) {
    if (str[i] == toReplace)
      newstr[i] = replaceWith;
    else 
      newstr[i] = str[i];
  }
  // How to change the value of the string being pointed to by *str to now be newstr?
}
```

Comment: Why not work on the string directly? Be careful on how the string is created, if you're testing on a string literal you'll not be able to change it as it is placed in read-only portion of memory.

Comment: Please show your actual function.

Comment: It is a string literal.

Comment: I don't see why you need to see the function to answer how to change the value of a string given only a pointer to it.

Comment: We need to see the code because your description is not clear and can be interpreted in different ways. Only the code itself is unambiguous.

Comment: What is `replaced` declared as?  What is `*str` pointing at?  You can't reliably modify what a string literal — attempting to do so will usually crash your program and definitely invokes 'undefined behaviour', which is a technical term from the standard and something to be avoided at all costs as there are no constraints on what a compiler does about undefined behaviour.

Comment: There is no way you can change a string *literal*. Just as you cannot change the integer literal `4`.

Comment: I understand that I cannot change a string literal which is why I need to make the pointer point to the new string.

Comment: you can't point to your new string as it is declared on the stack and will disappear after the function ends.  what you want to do is simply change the characters pointed to by str without creating a new string at all

Comment: not to mention that you have a whole lot of mistakes which might be confusing the situation as you need to solve multiple problems to get this code to wkrk

Comment: Note that you've not allocated enough space for the null byte at the end of the string, and you don't copy the null byte.  However, you shouldn't need the extra variable for the task you're attempting to do — you can modify the string in situ.  If you must make a copy, then either pass the array to hold the copy into the function, or use `malloc()` et al to allocate space and return a pointer to that space.  Do not attempt to return the local VLA (`newstr` in the code); that will fail horribly at run time.

Comment: In `strlen(src)`, what is `src`? This should be `strlen(str)`.

Comment: Right you are -- both of you.

Answer (score 1):

After digesting all the comments on your question, I've come to the understanding that you're trying to invoke your function in the following manner:

```
char * str = "string literal";  /* compiler should have warned you about assigning
                                   string literal to non-const pointer.            */
replace( str, 'i', 'u' );
printf( "%s\n", str );
```

Now, the problem with that is any attempts to modify the memory that `str` points to will be *undefined behaviour*.

Your attempt at a solution was to try to change the actual pointer inside the function.  But to do so, your `replace` function would need to accept a `char**`, and then allocate new memory.  That's not a nice approach in this case.  You really just need to modify the string in-place:

```
void replace(char* str, char toReplace, char replaceWith)
{
    while( *str )
    {
        if( *str == toReplace ) *str = replaceWith;
        str++;
    }
}
```

And how to deal with the string literal?  Well, the solution is simple.  Make an array:

```
char str[] = "string literal";
replace( str, 'i', 'u' );
printf( "%s\n", str );
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to change the value of the string being pointed to by *str to now
>   be newstr?

You can't due to (1) the way you pass `str` to the function as `char *s` **and** (2) because you declare `newstr` as a local variable in `replace`. (and probably for a whole host of other reasons that are not ascertainable from the limited section of code you posted)

When you pass a pointer to a function, the function receives a **copy** of the pointer with it *very own* and *very different* memory address. In other words when you declare the parameter `char *str` in your function parameter list, that creates a new pointer. (it still points to whatever is passed in `str`, but its variable address is very different from the original pointer address in the calling function - so nothing you do to the address of `str` will *ever* be reflected in the calling function.) If you want to assign a new address to a pointer in a function, you must *pass the original address* from the caller. e.g.

```
void replace(char **str, char toReplace, char replaceWith)
```

and then in your calling routine call it with:

```
replace (&origPtr, char toReplace, char replaceWith)
```

(as a style aside: don't use `CamelCase` variables in C, `camelcase` is proper)

Finally, since the address for `newstr` will be destroyed when you exit function `replace`, your only option for assigning the address of `newstr` to `*str` is to (1) declare `newstr` as `static`, or (2) dynamically allocate `newstr` (e.g. `char *newstr = malloc (sizeof *newstr * strLen + 1);`. Then you can assign the value of `newstr` to `str`. e.g.:

```
void replace(char **str, char toReplace, char replaceWith) {
    int strLen = strlen(*str);
    int i;
    char *newstr = malloc (sizeof *newstr * strLen + 1);
    if (!newstr) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < strLen; i++) {
        if ((*str)[i] == toReplace)
            newstr[i] = replaceWith;
        else 
            newstr[i] = (*str)[i];
    }
    newstr[strLen] = 0; /* nul-terminate (or use calloc to allocate) */
    free (*str);        /* MUST have been dynamically allocated in caller */
    *str = newstr;
}
```

(**note:** `str` must not have been statically declared in the calling function, and you must `free` the block of memory it points to or you will create a memory leak by overwriting the starting address to the block of memory it originally pointed to -- making it impossible to free the original block.)

**All of these reasons** are reasons why it is better to approach this problem by either changing the `toReplace` and `replaceWith` characters in place (presuming it `str` was an array and not a *string-literal*), or passing an additional array to fill with the replacement as a parameter (or as a pointer to allocate -- or return a pointer to a newly allocated block of memory containing the new string).

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: what is the need for **str in the function? To support multiple strings?

Comment: OK. you are freeing the string passed. But the function makes assumptions like str should have been allocated memory.

Comment: Because you will call the function by passing the address of the original pointer. (e.g. `replace (&origPtr, char toReplace, char replaceWith)`). So in your main code, you will have say `char *origPtr;` (which will be allocated and filled). You will pass it is `&origPtr` which is `char **`.